# How to distribute N approximately equispaced points with a given probability density?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, density-function, sampling, packing-problem

Let $x_i$ be points in $R^D$ space, $i = 0\ ..\ N-1$, where $N$ is fixed.

The problem is to distribute the $N$ points in the space so that their density is equal to given probability density $p(x)$, but at the same time keep them as far as possible from each other.

Here 'equispaced' means something similar to optimal ball packing problems.

Example (the density changes in a radial-symmetric way, but locally the points are densely packed):

[image: Example]

I understand the formulation is not exact, so I ask about the formulation too.

I tried to move points iteratively with the forces of attraction to the desired density and repulsion from each other, but I don't know how to derive the forces to get a desired density, for example, densely packed 3D Gaussian distribution.

Comment: In computer graphics this is related to the problem of *stippling*. See e.g. [this recent survey](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01528484) by Martin et al., 2017.

Comment: Up to now, the best I can do is Lloyd algorithm: move each point to the mass center of its Voronoi cell. The mass center is computed as an integral using the target density as weight. I cannot compute the integral directly, so I have to use sampling.

Comment: Knowing why you want to solve the problem would help us help you better. Do you want a way to produce nice graphics for teaching? Do you want to generate many independent samples of such configurations in order to do some kind of simulation?

Comment: @Ron Kaminsky, sorry for the late response, I was making something similar to unscented Kalman filter, where a probability density is represented with N points sampled from the distribution (in my case it was 64 points for 3D Gaussian ball), so I wanted to use N points optimally to cover the space. If two points are close to each other, they don't bring additional information because they behave like a single point.